# JavaScript page scroll states

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, scroll

I am developing a webpage where I use arrow button with two functions - to scroll to top and to attract attention of the visitors.

*There are two states of the button:*

↑ - Go to the top using onclick event `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'fast')` which is activated when user scrolled.

↓ - Attention attractor (default state on page load) - Does bouncing animation when `$(window).scrollTop() == 0` and user didn't scroll yet.

But when I reload mid-page, all the behavior goes wrong and the arrow button reacts in weird way to all events. I have tried numerous approaches to the problem but didn't find any functional solution.

Simplified code I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/rbusa/2m6RL/

Would you mind telling me what did I do wrong and eventually tell me how to fix this annoyance? Sorry for all the mess in the code, I am JS beginner.

Comment: The browser remembers the scrolls position on soft/reload, so if I'm getting you right you just need to first calculate the scroll position before doing any logic, where instead you immediately use an unsigned var `scrolled = "no";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is when you reload the browser is stuck to old scroll position. Tray adding this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Simple and easy to implent :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

welcome to javascript. a few things.. as noted, the page is maintaining it's position when reloaded, so some functions are getting initialized. also, you should get into the habit of keeping your js and css in the proper files for easier maintenance and debugging. i've refactored your code a bit and think i have it working as you expect now. the main fixes were scrolling the page back to the top as mentioned above, and removing rotate classes on the arrow in the head like this:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);
$('#arrow').removeClass('rotateup rotatedwn');
```

also, since it does the scrolltop function on load, i added the timeout for window.scroll to the bottom of the resetArrow function so that both wouldn't be called on init, which was causing confusion of states.

fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/yqbVu/

Comment: Concept of the code is pretty good but for my computer it's too resource heavy, scrolling to bottom takes 20% CPU and 300 Megs of RAM in Chrome. But thank you for telling me some tips on keeping the code clean :)